# structure, under certain conditions

Tags: html

I'm trying my hand at html but I don't know how to do it. That's my but doesnt work:(:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(local-name(), '.')]">
  <xsl:element name="{translate(local-name(), '.', '_')}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to deal with it?

Comment: Is that really what your input looks like? Or did you cut off some parts? It is not a well-formed XML document.

Comment: So which XSLT processor or which XSLT version do you use or can you use? It seems like a good job for XSLT 2/3 and a recursive function using `for-each-group group-starting-with`.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your interest. the first container of code is input, second - output. output is expected and I couldn't get it through xslt just manual modification (this is the expected result)

Comment: Markup in the form of e.g. `<li2>Term & Reversion</li2>` is not well-formed XML as the ampersand would need to be escaped as in e.g. `<li2>Term &amp; Reversion</li2>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a recursive grouping problem though the single example doesn't really spell out when to wrap and/or nest items as lists; nevertheless with XSLT 2 or 3 it could be tackled with a recursive function using `for-each-group`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:wrap" as="element()*">
      <xsl:param name="elements" as="element()*"/>
      <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$elements" group-adjacent="boolean(self::*[matches(local-name(), '^li[' || $level || '-9]+$')])">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                  <ul class="li{$level}">
                      <xsl:sequence select="mf:wrap(current-group(), $level + 1)"/>
                  </ul>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="*[matches(local-name(), '^li[0-9]+$')]">
      <li>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[*[matches(local-name(), '^li[0-9]+$')]]">
      <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mf:wrap(*, 1)"/>
      </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="uz">
      <h5>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </h5>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWK

Note that the list structure the above creates is a bit different, all `liX` items of the same `X` level are wrapped into a single `ul class="liX"` wrapper while your wanted sample at some places seems to wrap several items and at other places wrap only single items.